# Send the piece request to Udp peer using UDP Tracker Protocol

Tags: python, udp, bittorrent

I am building my own Bit-torrent Client(in python) where using UDP tracker Protocol I got the list of peers(IP and Port),now I cant figure out to how to send the piece request to that peer and receive the peer data in return

I am expecting a format of piece request according to UDP protocol through which I can request the piece data from that peer

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The [UDP tracker protocol](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0015.html) is just for announcing and retrieving peer lists, like the HTTP tracker protocol.
The UDP peer protocol ([bittorrent](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html) -> [uTP](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0029.html) -> UDP) is for peer communication and downloading pieces.

They're separate and you can't use one to do the other's job.

Comment: Could you please share the source for UDP peer protocol, as I could not find it over search

Comment: http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0029.html